# Obtain filename from url in R

Tags: r, curl, wget

I have an url like `http://example.com/files/01234` that when I click it from the browser downloads a zip file titled like `file-08.zip`

With wget I can download using the real file name by running

```
wget --content-disposition http://example.com/files/01234
```

Functions such as `basename` do not work in this case, for example:

```
> basename("http://example.com/files/01234")
[1] "01234"
```

I'd like to obtain just the filename from the URL in R and create a tibble with zip (files) names. No matter if using packages or `system(...)` command. Any ideas? what I'd like to obtain is something like

```
url                            | file
--------------------------------------------
http://example.com/files/01234 | file-08.zip
http://example.com/files/03210 | file-09.zip
...
```

Comment: would this work `paste0("file-", basename("http://example.com/files/01234"), ".zip")`?

Comment: if you have many urls, save it as vector and loop through to create the file name: `urls <- c("http://example.com/files/01234"); unlist(lapply(urls, function(x) paste0("file-", basename(x), ".zip")))`

Comment: `sapply` will give you the name of the url in return: `urls <- c("http://example.com/files/01234"); sapply(urls, function(x) paste0("file-", basename(x), ".zip"))`

Comment: @Sathish that didn't work but gave me an idea that (with more things) gives a valid solution

Comment: providing the _actual url_ — provided it's not illegal — would be super-helpful, esp since there are ways to get the name from such things that don't rely solely on the URL. but pls don't feel obliged to do so if illegal or unethical.

Comment: @hrbrmstr yeah, the problem is that the URL contains a token just in the middle of it and sharing that goes into a gray zone... I was able to solve this with the comments above and the answer is top down of this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With @Sathish contribution:

When URLs don't contain the file to download in the URL string a valid solution is

```
system("curl -IXGET -r 0-10 https://example.com/01234567 | grep attachment | sed 's/^.\\+filename=//'")
```

The idea is to read 10 bytes from the zip instead of the full file before obtaining file name, it will return `file-789456.zip` or the real zip name from that URL.

Answer (score 3):

Using the `httr` library, you can make a `HEAD` call and then parse he `content-disposition` header For example

```
library(httr)
hh <- HEAD("https://example.com/01234567")
get_disposition_filename <- function(x) {
  sub(".*filename=", "", headers(x)$`content-disposition`)
}
get_disposition_filename(hh)
```

This function doesn't check that the header actually exists so it's not very robust, but should work in the case where the server returns an alternate name for the downloaded file.